# Continuously retrieving the send data in php via AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I face one problem while coding, the thing is that I want to retrieve the same data from the sending script to another one let me explain

```
<button type="button" name="btn_more" data-vid="<?php echo $product; ?>" 
id="btn_more">Load more data</button> 
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?=$category;?>" id="category">
```

I have to buttons first calls the ajax and passes the parameter, second one holds the data from database

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(document).on('click', '#btn_more', function(){  
        var last_product_id = $(this).data("vid"); //this stands for <button>
        var cat=$("#cat").val(); //this one for hidden input
        $('#btn_more').html("Loading...");  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"ajax/shopProduct.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{last_product_id:last_product_id, category:category},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data) {  
                if(data != 'No rows') {  
                    $('#remove_row').remove();  
                    $('#load_data_table').append(data);  
                } else {  
                    $('#btn_more').html("No results");   
                }  
            }  
        });  
    });  
});
```

and here in shopProduct.php i get the post data

```
if($_POST) {  
    $let = filter_var($_POST["last_product_id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
    $category= filter_var($_POST["category"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}
```

And based on these two values I make an SQL statement to retrieve data, and display some info as a output, and again show the load more button as

```
<div id="remove_row"><button type="button" name="btn_more" data-vid="<?php 
 echo $product; ?>" id="btn_more">Load more data</button></div>
```

The actual problem is that the `$category` value stops existing as the second click calls from other script. How can i continuously fetch `$category` value from the first script to the current one?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong selector. Change this line -

```
var cat =$("#cat").val()
```

to

```
var category = $("#category").val()
```

Comment: first call work, as it is sends the $category values, second call of button processes from the another script, and there is no more value on $category
 variable it gets empty

Comment: But your hidden input element has id=category.How can you get its value even for the first time..!!!

Comment: value="" holds info from the database

Comment: Than you should also add your controllers code, so that we can know.